# Python can't describe two varibles

Tags: python, string, math

I am trying to make a simple program to calculate the area of a triangle.
But at the end, python does not recognize the str function I am using. I have little to no experience on Python so if this is a stupid question, then that is why.

I have tried renaming the variables and looking at other questions on Stack Overflow. None really helped

```
promt = input ("Type square or quadrilateral : ")
if promt == "square" :
  print ("Square has been chosen")
  #s stands for square and t stands for triangle
  sbase = input ("Type the base : ")
  sheight = input ("Type the height : ")
  sfinal = sbase(str)*sheight(str)
  print (sfinal)
```

But the Python terminal (repl) brings back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    sfinal = sbase(str)*sheight(str)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What do you *expect* `sbase(str)` to do?? `sbase` is a *string*, you are *calling* it by using parentheses, i.e. `some_object()` is "calling some_object", but strings are not callable. In any case, you probably just wanted to convert to integers, i.e. `sbase = int(input(...))` and `sheight = int(input(...))`

Comment: It should be `int(sbase) * int(sheight)`

Comment: You should read what [str](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str) is.

Comment: Thank you Barmar and juapa!

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer, all credit goes to Barmar, who first made a comment containing the answer.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
promt = input ("Type square or quadrilateral : ")
if promt == "square" :
  print ("Square has been chosen")
  #s stands for square and t stands for triangle
  sbase = input ("Type the base : ")
  sheight = input ("Type the height : ")
  sfinal = int(sbase)*int(sheight)
  print (sfinal)
```